# Linux can't print long ASCII list returned from Erlang prgram

Tags: linux, erlang

I have a Erlang program and the return value is a very long printable list. But when the length of the list is bigger than 65534, what I can see on terminal is bare integer list instead of ASCII characters.

Here is my Erlang code:

```
-module(test).
-compile([export_all]).

print_long(Num) ->
        [(X rem 95) + 32  || X <- lists:seq(1,Num)].
```

The way I call the Erlang module from terminal:

```
erl_call -a 'test print_long [65534]' -n 'nodeName@hostname' -c SOMECOOKIE
```

Is there any limitation on return value in Linux?

I suppose I can slice the output but how to print them on terminal?
I tried erlang:dispaly/0 but it doesn't work.

Comment: I do not have the command `erl_call` here (R17, ERTS 6.0). Am I missing something? EDIT: when I run your code in an Erlang shell, I see proper characters.

Comment: This command is at <YourErlDir>/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-X.X.X/bin/erl_call.
I don't know if there is any way else you can invoke a Erlang program from command line (not Erlang Shell). As long as you can get return value from an Erlang program, I think the issue will be reproduced.

Comment: I tried it again with `erl_call`, but still can't reproduce the error. As a side note, you can run commands without an erlang shell as well. Check out the parameters `-eval`, `-run` and `-s` for example.

Comment: Hi evnu. Unfortunately I can't find the root cause of this issue. But in our project the solution is writing the long list into a temp file with file:open/2. Then cat the file from calling shell script.

Comment: @evnu. In shell script: result=`cat $filename`; ehco $result. This workaround runs well for us.
And yes, I agree with you that erlang module can be called without opening an erlang shell. But as we need to call from a shell script, erl_call is recommended by [link](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_call.html). 
*Options, which cause stdin to be read, can be used with advantage as scripts from within (Unix) shell scripts.*

Answer (score 0):

I think I find a workaround and have to answer my own question.

When the calling flow is

```
SomeScript -> erl_call -> ErlangModuleAndFunc
```

The script can get the terminal info (like `/dev/pts/69`) with `tty` command. Then, the terminal info can be transferred to Erlang as an argument. In Erlang, when programmer wants to print something on terminal, he/she just call `os:cmd('echo YourWords > /dev/pts/69')`.

It's not best solution, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ erl -eval 'io:put_chars(test:print_long(65534))' -noshell -nostdio -s init stop | wc -c
65534
```

Works as expected. It seems problem is how you use `erl_call`. What do you get and what do you expect? Is `nodeName@hostname` up and running?